# Função Crontab não funciona

Tags: php, linux, cron, comandos

Tenho um script em php que realiza (deveria pelo menos) algumas gravações em um txt:

```
25 11 * * 1-5 wget -q --spider http://10.24.0.42/felipe_projetos/DD/CREATE_TABLE.NULL.IN.php
```

Entretanto a gravação não ocorre. Suspeitei de inicio que fosse o erro fosse no proprio PHP, mas quando executo o arquivo direto no navegador a gravação acontece, não sei se os comandos estão errados pois uso outros dois comandos similares que funcionam perfeitamente:

```
30 22 * * 1-5 wget -q --spider http://10.24.0.42/felipe_projetos/DD/CREATE_TABLE.NULL.php


00 7 * * 1-5 wget -q --spider http://10.24.0.42/felipe_projetos/Poc/ch_ch.php
```

Alterei o arquivo para ter permissão 777 achando que podia ser algum tipo de bloqueio, mas mesmo assim não funcionou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conheço duas maneiras de agendar tarefas no crom:

1 - executar o comando `crontab -e` que abrira uma janela dando uma leve descrição de como vc pode agendar as tarefas no cron, onde vc pode simplesmente colar seu cron já criado, ao final a janela deve se parecer com isso:

```
# Edit this file to introduce tasks to be run by cron.
# 
# Each task to run has to be defined through a single line
# indicating with different fields when the task will be run
# and what command to run for the task
# 
# To define the time you can provide concrete values for
# minute (m), hour (h), day of month (dom), month (mon),
# and day of week (dow) or use '*' in these fields (for 'any').# 
# Notice that tasks will be started based on the cron's system
# daemon's notion of time and timezones.
# 
# Output of the crontab jobs (including errors) is sent through
# email to the user the crontab file belongs to (unless redirected).
# 
# For example, you can run a backup of all your user accounts
# at 5 a.m every week with:
# 0 5 * * 1 tar -zcf /var/backups/home.tgz /home/
# 
# For more information see the manual pages of crontab(5) and cron(8)
# 
# m h  dom mon dow   command
25 11 * * 1-5 wget -q --spider http://10.24.0.42/felipe_projetos/DD/CREATE_TABLE.NULL.IN.php
```

Nesse exemplo não à a necessidade de definir um usuário.

2 - Editar ou criar seu cron em **/etc/crontab-d/meucron**

```
vi /etc/cron.d/meucron
```

agora cole seu cron

```
25 11 * * 1-5 root wget -q --spider http://10.24.0.42/felipe_projetos/DD/CREATE_TABLE.NULL.IN.php
```

Note que nesse segundo método defini um usuário para executar a ação.
Após editar/criar seu cron e salva-lo, reinicie o **crontab**.

Para esse segundo método vc deve ser root para criar ou editar arquivos em **/etc/cron.d/**

Answer (score 0):

Seta um usuário para executar sua cron e certifique-se que esse usuário possa executar o php e tem permissão de gravar no diretório de destino:

**Ex. Crontab:**
30 22 * * 1-5 USUARIO wget -q --spider http://10.24.0.42/felipe_projetos/DD/CREATE_TABLE.NULL.php